# Get token with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, http, retrofit2

Now I am having an issue with authorization by Retrofit and website API.

My code based on the following:

[How can I take token with Retrofit2 in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056352/how-can-i-take-token-with-retrofit2-in-android-studio)

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#define-the-endpoints

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library

**Here is my MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.some.some/v1/";

SomeAPI userClient;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

userClient  = retrofit.create(SomeAPI.class);

login();

}

private void login() {
    Auth login = new Auth("123456", "12345678");
    Call<User> call = userClient.login(login);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                token = response.body().getToken();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Token is not truth :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

**Here is my Some API interface:**

```
public interface SomeAPI {

    @POST("token")
    Call<User> login(@Body Auth login);

}
```

**Here is my Auth.java:**

```
public class Auth {
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public Auth(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Here is my User.java:**

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String token;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return  email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getToken(){return token;}
    public void setToken(String token){this.token = token;}
}
```

***About website API on the following screenshots:***
 [image: Request]

[image: Response]

***So the main question: what is wrong in my code? Why I am can't to get token?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your api require two properties `login` and `password` and you are sending `user` and `password` see your `Auth` class change variable name `user` to `login`

and

in `onResponse` method change

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
   ...
}
```

to

```
if (response.code() == 201) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: tried this and still can't to get token - getting "Token is not truth :("; p.s.:edited code in question.

Comment: in `onResponse` method change `if (response.isSuccessful()){` to `if (response.code() == 201) {`

Comment: changing to `if (response.code() == 201)` - didn't help.

Comment: then I prefer to check through breakPoints because your api is calling successfully

Comment: also test your api on PostMan or some other api testing tool to check whether your token is returning in body or header